# How do I get https://outlook.office365.com/ to stop notifications in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, office-365

I get incessant notification sounds that do not respect macOS 10.14.6 settings and there is nothing seemingly relevant in Chrome or Outlook
settings either.

For some reason privacy in macOS settings does not have sound output devices listed so that I can whitelist some (or blacklist some.)

Comment: as a temporary fix, disable chrome notification's sound in notification Preferences

Comment: I did and that made no difference. it still pesters me with the sound on incoming mail

Comment: ended up getting rid of that in chrome logging into mail from safari now that I got a compelling incentive to do so